# How to call a function from a component in another component?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

My problem is that I have two components (lets call them **comp1** and **comp2**) and I have to call the function `show_it(list)` in **comp1** from **comp2** with some data from **comp2**. So currently it works out if i trigger it easily with a button, which is implemented in **comp2**. But my intension is now, that i want to trigger the function of **comp2** in **comp1** by clicking a label with `(click)` event. Does anyone have a solution for my problem?

**How I call comp1 and comp2 in my home.html:**

```
 <comp1 [list]="lists" (emitList)="onListUpdate($event)"></comp1>
 <comp2 [list]="additionalInformationList"></comp2>
```

**onListUpdate function of my home.ts:**

```
onListUpdate(list: {item:string}[]){
    this.additionalInformationList=list;
    console.log(list);
}
```

**My .html of comp1:**

```
div>
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let list of list">
        <ion-label (click)="updateList(list)">{{list.item.free_text}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox *ngIf="list.item.checkbox==true"  disabled="false"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**My .ts of comp1:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'caiditems',
  templateUrl: 'caiditems.html'
})
export class CaiditemsComponent {
  transformedList=[];

  @Input()
  list = []; 

  @Output() 
  emitList = new EventEmitter<{item:string}[]>();

  constructor() {
    this.emitList.emit(this.list);
  }

  updateList(list) {
     if(list.item.additional_information!=null){
       this.transformedList=[
        {item: {id: list.item.id, free_text: list.item.free_text, checkbox: list.item.checkbox, additional_information: list.item.additional_information}}]
      console.log("not empty")
     }
     else{
       this.transformedList=[{item: {id: list.item.id, free_text: list.item.free_text, checkbox: list.item.checkbox, additional_information: ""}}]
       console.log("empty")
     }
     this.emitAdditionalinformations(this.transformedList);
     console.log('additional information list updated')
  }

  emitAdditionalinformations(transformedList){
    this.emitList.emit(this.transformedList);
    console.log('list emited');
  }
```

**My .html of comp2:**

```
<div>
  <button ion-button (click)="show_it(list)">show it to meeeeeee</button><br>
  <ion-label>{{additionalinformation}}<br><br></ion-label>
</div>
```

**My .ts of comp2:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'caidadditionalinformations',
  templateUrl: 'caidadditionalinformations.html'
})
export class CaidadditionalinformationsComponent {
  additionalinformation="hi";

@Input()
list = []; 

constructor() {  
}

show_it(list){
  console.log(list);
  if(list[0].item.additional_information!=""){
      console.log(list[0].item.additional_information);
      this.additionalinformation=list[0].item.additional_information;
   }
  else{
      this.additionalinformation="no additional informations";
   }
}
```

Comment: could you provide your code in stackblitz project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this code snipped:

```
 <comp1 [list]="lists" (emitList)="onListUpdate($event)"></comp1>
 <comp2 [list]="additionalInformationList"></comp2>
```

I'm assuming both `comp1` and `comp2` are children of the `HomePage`. When you click on a label from the `comp1`, the `onListUpdate($event)` method is executed in the `HomePage`, right?

You can get a reference of the `comp2` component in the `HomePage`, and then call the `show_it()` method with that reference.

It'd be something like this:

```
@Component(...)
export class HomePage {

  // Get a reference of the component instance
  @ViewChild(CaidadditionalinformationsComponent) comp2: CaidadditionalinformationsComponent;

  onListUpdate(list: {item:string}[]){
    this.additionalInformationList = list;
    console.log(list);

    // Use the reference to call the public method
    this.comp2.show_it(list);
  }

}
```

Please let me know if this does not make sense in the context of your application, maybe creating a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/ionic) project would help us to understand your specific scenario a little bit better.

There are some other ways to share data among components:

1. Using a shared service, where you can keep the data, and both components can read the data from there
2. Using [Ionic events](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/util/Events/) so that both components can publish/subscribe to changes in the data, without the need of the HomePage to be the mediator.

Comment: Exactly what I looked for! Worked out for me, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped @Marcel :)